# Eclipse: Turn on syntax-highlighting for Classes and Objects

Tags: eclipse, syntax-highlighting

Is there any possibility to turn on the highlighting for Classes and Objects in Eclipse like it is in Visual Studio? At the moment only the Variable names are highlighted.

Left: Eclipse, Right: Visual Studio 2012

Image: (http://image-uploader.de/bild.php/9468,unbenanntHU9EZ.jpg)

[image: Visual difference between Eclipse(left) and Visual Studio (right)]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Syntax Coloring

Then just switch on / off what you want highlighted.

Comment: The question was intended for Java. But note that Syntax Coloring can be enabled/customized for other languages supported by Eclipse through "Preference -> [Language] -> Editor -> Syntax Coloring

Answer (score 12):

try this

```
Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Editor -> Mark Occurrences
```

Comment: Except that isn't what he asked for. Mark Occurrences dynamically highlights the selected token anywhere it's found in the file.

Comment: Thanks! for the "occurrences"; Eclipse wasn't marking my occurrences elsewhere in the file.

Answer (score 2):

Full explanation here of how to add advanced syntax marking http://www.javalobby.org/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=15586