# Eclipse Current Member Syntax Highlighting in dark theme

Tags: eclipse, settings

I have installed the Chrome Theme 4 (1.7.6), Moonrise Dark UI Theme (0.8.8) and Eclipse Color Theme (0.13.0). I set the Appearance->Color Theme to Obsidian with the "Set all background colors to default" box checked. I then set the Appearance->Theme to MoonRise.

This combination makes for a great dark background. However, there is one problem. When putting the cursor on a member of a struct, the syntax highlighting makes the member name unreadable. See the picture below.

[image: Highlight of struct member in dark Eclipse Theme]

I have been looking through the various color settings for some time, but I cannot find the color setting for this particular form of highlighting. Does anyone know what setting this is so I can change it?

Eclipse Install Info:

> Eclipse IDE for C/C++ Developers
>
> Version: Kepler Service Release 1
>   Build id: 20130919-0819

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566517/eclipse-turn-on-syntax-highlighting-for-classes-and-objects), while for the Java editor, led me to the answer for this question. This type of highlighting is handled under Preferences->C/C++->Editor->Mark Occurrences. There is a link from there to Pereferences->General->Appearance->Annotations. This particular occurance is considered a "Write Occurrence". Changing the color for "Write Occurrences" fixed the problem.